# Code reuse tools

Tags: code-reuse

I usually maintain code snippets that I can resuse in a Wikidpad personal wiki with a small index page that can take me to any code that I want.

I want to share these snippets with my team and am looking for easy ways to do it.

Are there any tools that would help me setup such a repository? Or should I simply install a wiki and port my personal wiki there?

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs, perhaps? Search-ability is the key. No one has time to cross-index, keyword-stuff, and organize "snippets" into complex ontologies.

Also, remember that when someone reuses code, they also reuse the bugs, limitations, and performance issues you may have worked out in subsequent revisions. The best way to reuse code is not to copy it, but to document it and make it accessible for *direct* reuse.

Comment: I agree categorizing the code is not required here. I normally put a  brief description, sometimes a change log, on the same page just before the code. So I could search by the words in the desription if i wanted to.

I could put together a small google doc or google sites page (is this service still available?).

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs have a code-snippet utility built into them. e.g. Visual Studio has [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28VS.80%29.aspx) Manager.
Or perhaps an addin like Resharper. My point being find something that integrates nicely with the IDE that your team uses.

Comment: Ok, will look for eclipse or netbeans plugins for this.

But still, how can i share that with the team? I need a central storage :(

Comment: Depends on the exact tool you choose to use. e.g. with the Visual studio snippet manager, all members could configure their IDEs to use a shared folder on the network to house the common snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use code [snipplr](http://snipplr.com)

Comment: Can this suport private (restricted to a user group) repos? Will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and reusable solution: a repository with web interface like subversion. Also Github can be a good option since you don't need installation